# Error importing .net webservice with wsimport

Tags: c#, java, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I have a webservice which has been coded with c#. 
I want to use it in java app so i am trying to import it with wsimport with these parameters :

```
wsimport -keep -verbose -B-XautoNameResolution http://localhost:50358/WebService.asmx?wsdl
```

I have a class like this in my webservice :

```
 public class ReturnClass
{
    int _returnCode;
    DataTable _outputDataDT;


    public int ReturnCode { set { _returnCode = value; } get { return _returnCode; } }
    public DataTable OutputDataDT { set { _outputDataDT = value; } get { return _outputDataDT; } }

}
```

If i use a Datatable variable, wsimport returns this error :

> [ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve thi
>   s conflict.
>    line 16 of `http://localhost:50358/WebService.asmx?wsdl`
>
> [ERROR] The following location is relevant to the above error   line
>   17 of `http://localhost:50358/WebService.asmx?wsdl`

But if i remove datatable variable, it works, but i need datatable.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed all Datatables, and used List<> instead of Datatable

Answer (score 0):

Look at your schemas, JAXB is seeing two properties with the same name and is having trouble figuring out what to call the fields in the generated Java code. You need to create an external custom binding file. Read more about it at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html The wsimport command has a -b option which you can use to specify a binding file.

Answer (score 0):

Post your wsdl.

Also: it might be a type/element naming clash, in which case you can get away with simply using

```
<nameXmlTransform>
  [ <typeName [ suffix="suffix" ]
              [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <elementName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                 [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <modelGroupName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                    [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
  [ <anonymousTypeName [ suffix="suffix" ]
                       [ prefix="prefix" ] /> ]
</nameXmlTransform>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148550